# getting database detail value and list of related values

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

i want to display detail post of related posts. i am using `get_object_or_404` to try to get a single value and a list of associated with the `categories_pk`. The code below does not work?

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='article')


   def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

views.py

```
def NewsDetail(request, pk):
    #single post detail
    obj = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)

    # related post list
    related = Article.objects.filter(categories__pk=obj)

    context = {
       'object': obj,
       'related': related
    }
    return render(request, 'news/detail.html', context)
```

post_detail.html

```
{{ object.title }} #sigle detail post is working

{% for article in related %} #related posts list is not working
{{ object.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use django-taggit, it was made for this scenario.
https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This way  is grab all related categories but i don't want categories i want to grab all articles related of this post